# How much does a bit coin cost?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

The reason I ask is because I just received an e-mail from someone who claims to have commandeered my cell phone camera and also my address book.  They said they would overlay my picture while watching 
porn if I do not send them 869 usd worth of bit coins, or the will send my customized video to everyone in my address book.  The email header didn’t have any IP addresses or a MAC address.  The email address itself would not resolve to a valid domain. If anyone can help me find the owner of this bit coin address I would really appreciate it.
B‌T‌C‌ ad‌dre‌ss: 1Lq8TnU33SMFUXcyGYmwkfriaBAfEoX5Co 
Thank you very much.
David

Comment: They don't have a video of you. Common scam. Buy bitcoin, but don't send it to them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question in the title is subject to changing over time, and the titular question is not the main purpose of asking the question

Answer (score 2):

You've asked about five different questions here.

- This is a standard scam and there is no reason to think they actually have anything.
- There is no way to trace the owner of a Bitcoin address. That's why these scammers ask for payment in Bitcoin.
- The cost of one bitcoin varies continuously, just like stock prices or currency exchange rates, but you can easily find the current exchange rate by Googling for something like "current bitcoin price".